# In Cloud Firestore rules - How do I check if a key is null

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

In **Cloud Firestore Rules** - I have a document called `task` and I want to see if some data (`assignee` field) is null / don't exists.

I've tried:

1. `resource.data.assignee == null` - Does not work (Error)
2. `!resource.data.hasAll(['assignee'])` - Does not work (Error)

From the documentation - it states that this indeed creates an error:

`// Error, key doesn't exist
allow read: if resource.data.nonExistentKey == 'value';`

Comment: Here is the full rules file - https://github.com/Metaburn/doocrate/blob/master/firestore.rules
As I understand `resource` is a document since I'm using `match /tasks/{anyTask} {`
From firebase documentation on resource - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#resource_1

Comment: I don't need to check for a document - I know the document is there.
I want to check for a field inside that document.
so for `/tasks/my-task` - `tasks` is the collection. `my-task` is the document. And inside there is a field `assignee` - I want to see if it is null or not and I can't

Comment: There is a `resource.data.keys()` function, try using `hasAll(['assignee'])` on this instead.

Comment: @Callam Look at the Question at number 2 - As I've wrote - !resource.data.hasAll(['assignee']) - Does not work (Creates an Error)

Comment: Maybe you'll have some luck with `!resource.data.keys().hasAll(['assignee'])`

Comment: I'll make it an answer, glad we got there!

Comment: Boom @Callam You got it.

Comment: Yes, you missed `keys()`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Reading the list comparisons of the Firestore Security rules documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/security#hasall), we can see that `hasAll` returns true if all values are present in the list.

```
// Allow read if one list has all items in the other list
allow read: if ['username', 'age'].hasAll(['username', 'age']);
```

The `request.resource.data` is a map containing the fields and values. In order to use `hasAll`, we must first get the keys as a list of values as shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/security#keys).

```
!resource.data.keys().hasAll(['assignee'])
```

Comment: Should `!('asignee' in resource.data.keys())` work too? Another thing to note is this, from the rules docs: 

"Fields not provided in the request which exist in the resource are added to `request.resource.data`. Rules can test whether a field is modified by comparing `request.resource.data.foo` to `resource.data.foo` knowing that every field in the `resource` will also be present in `request.resource` even if it was not submitted in the write request.", so there may be times when the key exists and you aren't expecting it to...

Comment: @menehune23 That's true, and it makes it really difficult to tell if the client app has _not_ included a field, in the case where it might already exist in the resource. In addition, the copying of resource to request fields is _not_ honoured by the rules simulator, so you can build an update in the simulator which works, but _won't_ work in a real app... Very frustrating.

Answer (score 14):

Looking at the docs - https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map

```
k in x  - Check if key k exists in map x
```

so this should work (without the keys())

```
!('assignee' in resource.data)
```

Answer (score 5):

if you want to make sure a key is null you need to check that this key is not part of the resource keys property:
`!resource.data.keys().hasAny(['assignee'])`

you can also use `hasAll` or `hasOnly`. more info [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List.html)